# Error when compiling python with Cython: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, compiler-errors, cython

I'm trying to compile simple python function with Cython.

I run the my setup.py

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

But getting the error

```
running build_ext; 
building 'cythonfn' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Below is my python configuration.

[image]

I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2012,2013 and 2015-2019 redistributables.

Any suggestion how to find vcvarsall.bat?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2838827/2264936

Comment: In the past I've found that simply `import setuptools` in `setup.py` is enough (setuptools seems to have a better ability to find it then just distutils. Obviously I don't know what's in your `setup.py` right now

Comment: @chiefenne as far as I'm aware mingw no longer works with any recent version of Python (since about 3.4 I think) so I don't think that answer is good advice